# What is line-height "normal" in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, typography

By default `line-height` is `"normal"` in Chrome. This is even shown as the computed value. It is obviously different from `line-height: 1`. Is there a number representation for the "normal" `line-height` and/or can I specify "*n*-times normal line height"?

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values

Comment: Indeed, the answer to that question answers my (original) question as well. VTC as duplicate.